# In method / function overloading, must every version be reimplemented?

Tags: c++

I want to implement double dispatch.
Say I have a class like so:

```
class Entity
{
   public:
   virtual void eventHandler(Message* msg, Entity* entity);
}
```

Then eventually I create derived entities. Say I eventually create several different types which derive from Entity. Do I need to forward declare them all in Entity.hpp then make methods for each one? What if my class names change, it seems to add a maintenance overhead?

The other thing I was wondering is if I need to re implement each one in each class.

Say Player needs to respond to the event handler of an Item. Does that mean I need to provide empty implementations for all the other ones?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In double-dispatch you have two class hierarchies, A and B. A has a bunch of overloaded methods that take different  versions of B and B has a single method that takes A. Each of these methods need one argument. You need to declare all different versions in the A base class and implement all of them in A derived classes. You also need to reimplement the B method in each B derived class. Yes this means A knows about each one of the B versions in advance.

Let's say you have 3 concrete messages, a KeyboardMessage, a MouseMessage ans a ScreenMessage. You also have a growing family of Entities, at this time it consists of a Widget and a Gadget. In a C++-like pseudocode

```
class Message { virtual void dispatch(Entity* e) = 0 }
class KeyboardMessage : Message { void dispatch(Entity* e) { e->process(this); }}
class MouseMessage : Message { void dispatch(Entity* e) { e->process(this); }}
class ScreenMessage : Message { void dispatch(Entity* e) { e->process(this); }}

class Entity
  {
     virtual void process (KeyboardMessage* m) {... default impl...}
     virtual void process (MouseMessage* m) {... default impl...}
     virtual void process (ScreenMessage* m) {... default impl...}
  }

 class Widget : Entity
  {
     void process (KeyboardMessage* m) {... impl...}
     void process (MouseMessage* m) {... impl...}
     void process (ScreenMessage* m) {... impl...}
  }

class Gadget : Entity
  {
     void process (KeyboardMessage* m) {... impl...}
     void process (MouseMessage* m) {... impl...}
     void process (ScreenMessage* m) {... impl...}
  }
```

Now you can add other concrete entities with ease. To add another message, you will have to add a method to Entity, possibly reimplement it in some derived classes, but recompile all derived (since the base has changed).

See, no casts here.

Comment: So should I just solve it via casting ? It seems better, I don't see what is so bad about it.

Comment: Casting does not solve anything, don't do it. Read up on the Visitor Pattern in Wikipedia.

Comment: Thanks for that code, Ill study it and try to understand it :)

Comment: You start the process with `m->dispatch(e)`, this will call say `MouseEntity::dispatch(Entity*)` and then `e->process(MouseMessage*)` which goes to say `Wisget::process(MouseMessage*)`.

Comment: What if Gaget does not need to process mouse messages, must he still provide an implementation?

Comment: @Milo Note that there are default implementations of all message handlers in `Entity`. You cannot omit any of them or make them pure virtual, otherwise the code won't compile. They can be empty of course. If `Gaget` doesn't need to reimplement some of the handlers, it doesn't have to. In this case the default implementation will be called.